# Ajax response into javascript variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In fact, I am working on a small PHP script and I use this code to make an ajax query

```
 var CODE = $('.code').val();
         var CASE = $('.code').attr('case');
  $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax.php',
            data:'code='+CODE+'&case='+CASE,
            success:function(html){

            }
        });
```

the response is like that

```
<span class="name">Yassine</span>
<span class="email">Yassine@gmail.com</span>
```

I want to store those results as javascript variables like this:

```
Var name = Yassine
Var email = Yassine@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery()`, `.eq()`, `.text()`

```
var response = $(html);
var name = response.eq(0).text();
var email = response.eq(1).text();
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( The Html responses are SPANS HTML tags.

Comment: @YassineDevlopper Can you describe "It doesn't work"? _"The Html responses are SPANS HTML tags"_ Yes

Comment: The response is like this : <span class="name">Yassine</span> I want to Put Yassine as variable so I'm looking for a way to select the span by using the class name and get interior value . Any other way will be OK.

Comment: @YassineDevlopper _"The response is like this : <span class="name">Yassine</span> I want to Put Yassine as variable so I'm looking for a way to select the span by using the class name and get interior value ."_ Yes, `js` at post should achieve expected result; see jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/16nq024f/

Comment: @YassineDevlopper You could alternatively use `.filter()` to select element by `className`, e.g.; `response.filter(".name").text()` , see https://jsfiddle.net/16nq024f/2/